# Create custom actions in Django admin site (not list actions)

Tags: ajax, django, custom-action

I'm new to django and I'm trying to figure out how to create custom actions inside admin site.
Let's say I want to create some sort of custom form with fancy ajax based ui. 
What I would normally do in .NET/PHP/Ruby is prepare some js code and a service that will be called via ajax and return json or even html.
A more concrete example could be an auto complete box to manage a many to one relationship. What should I do to build such a system inside the django admin site? (I know there are a couple of ready to use solution for this. But I'm not interested: just for study purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case (a fancier widget), ModelAdmin has several useful hooks like [ModelAdmin.form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) and [ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides).

Creating a custom Django Form Widget is more elegant, but if the widget is pure JS (like many jQuery widgets), most of the time it is not worth - just [override the change_form.html admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for the Model in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) and the [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_form_template) of the `ModelAdmin`.

So you're free to inject any CSS and JS you like. Take look at this [presentation](http://lincolnloop.com/static/slides/2010-djangocon/customizing-the-admin.html#slide1) to get the basic idea.

Comment: I'll have to study more in depth this presentation but after a quick overview I think what I was looking for is Custom Views in Admin site.
Coming from other mvc frameworks I still find confusing django design patterns and I don't realize views in django (mtv) are actually controllers (mvc).
There may be though other easier ways. I'll have to investigate.

Comment: To be honest: I am not sure why you want to build your custom forms in the admin. Django has many helpers (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) to build completely custom views and forms. The admin is only a helper for quick data entry. So you shouldn't bother too much adjusting the admin to your needs, if you already have a clear idea of what to do.

Comment: It's a complete new world to me so I might be missing the solution to my problem even if it's under my nose. Anyway the admin site is the main (only) reason that can make me choose django for web development.
If I can't get advantage of it and customize the missing pieces to fit my needs, then there's no point choosing django (that's my opinion).
I can't consider the admin site just a quick and dirty data entry tool.

Comment: Okay, but this is getting a bit too general for a simple SO question ;-) If the answer helped you, you could mark your question solved or reformulate it, so that a clear answer is possible.